# Scale animation - How to stop child view animation

Tags: android, animation, scale, viewgroup, objectanimator

I have a layout(parent view) and a textview(child view) inside this layout. Applying scale animation on parent view but when scale animation is applied to parent view its child view also scales.Is there any way to stop child from animation ? Including the code

Layout File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tfg.social.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Top Layout"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Animation method

```
protected void expandLayout(View view) {
    ObjectAnimator scaleUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 5f);
    scaleUpY.setDuration(1000);
    AnimatorSet scaleAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
    scaleAnimation.play(scaleUpY);
    scaleAnimation.start();

}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: included the code in the question

Comment: If a container(Linear Layout) is animated, all the children contained by it will animate. However you can have a different XML structure, may be using a relative layout, to have the effect you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out -

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = val;
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});

valueAnimator.setDuration(300);
valueAnimator.start();
```